# Trying to enter a value in a range based on the value of a different range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with a column named "Character" consisting of a list of names. I have a constant that's outside of the table I want to check this against, and if it matches I want to put a constant named "period_selected" in a column named "Action".

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Action()
   ' Set objects
   Dim rng As Range, char As Range
   Set rng = Range("Table1[Character]")

   ' Loop through Character column
   For Each char In rng
         'If character is the Active Player, 
      If char = Range("Active_Player") Then
         'enter the period_selected value in Action column               
         Else
      End If
   Next char
End Sub
```

So the part I can't figure out is how to apply the value in the Action column while looping through the Character column.

This is my first attempt at writing something this in depth so I feel like I'm in a little over my head. All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could just use `Offset`, e.g. `Offset(,1)` if Action were the next column to the right..

Answer (score 0):

a possible way:

```
If char.Value = Range("Active_Player") Then Intersect(Range("Table1[Action]"), char.EntireRow).Value = "period_selected" '
```

while a more elegant way would be using `ListObject` object

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? Like I said I'm just learning and I'm not familiar with `ListObject`.

Comment: If you want to learn about `ListObject` object you have plenty of resources in the web, just a google away from you. But does the code I provided work for you?

Comment: No, it's not working. I adjusted your code for some typos and for what I'm looking for and have this:

`If char = Range("Active_Player") Then Range("Table1[Action]").Rows(char.Row-1).Value = Range("period_selected")`

But when I run that nothing happens. If I take the -1 out, it enters the value 2 rows below where I expect it to.

Comment: I think your table's header is not in row 1 as mine test one was. See edited answer for a _general_ code

Comment: @Awspry, did you get through it?

Comment: Kind of. I found an issue in my logic and had to rework how I was going about things. But your script eventually worked. Thank you. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Then I'd appreciate your accepting my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you!